# What do I put in date_default_timezone_set?

Tags: php, timezone

I'm not from the US but I want to use `date_default_timezone_set` and set it to Englewood, Colorado. What do I use? I can't find any `America/Englewood` or `America/Colorado` in [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php). Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As google tells me that Colorado is in the 'Mountain Time Zone' use `US/Mountain` from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Answer (score 1):

The correct TZDB zone name is `America/Denver`.

`US/Mountain` is an alias that presently resolves to `America/Denver`, but it may not always be that way in the future.

The `US/*` aliases are there for backwards compatibility only, and do not follow the normal naming conventions of the [IANA/Olson](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) time zones that PHP uses.

From [the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php):

> Warning
>
> Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.

See also:  [Are 'US/Eastern' and 'US/Central' and 'US/Pacific' deprecated for strftime or just PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9523917/634824)