# PHP DateTimeZone error

Tags: php, datetime

I've been looking for a while, it used to work but it does'nt anymore and I can't find why. Does one of you have an idea?

```
$utc_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time, new DateTimeZone('US/Eastern'));
$utc_time->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC")); // This line returns the error.
return $utc_time->format($dateformat);
```

I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimeZone() on a non-object`.

Thanks a lot for your help, I hope it's something dumb and that I was just lost...

Comment: which PHP version are you using ? > 5.2.0 ?

Comment: Don't forget that `$time` needs to be a string representing the time.

Comment: Your code works just fine with PHP 5.3 See **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ykBBNm)** That means that the only problem is with `$time` variable

Comment: Don't use the `US/Eastern` alias.  Use `America/New_York` instead.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447862/634824)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), it returns FALSE on failure, which leads to your error.

What is the value of `$time` ?

Comment: I was using $time in a wront format. I just make sure I use the good one now. Thanks!